# Position a div below an absolute positioned div without nesting

Tags: html, css

So I have this absolute positioned div in the centre of the page. I wish to put a navigation menu below this div, but i can't nest it with the other div. Is there anyway to do this?

*Note:* In the snippet code example the position `absolute:bottom;` doesn't work, but you get the idea.

HTML:

```html
<div class="content">Hello world</div>
<div class="menu">home | info | about us | contact</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    position:relative;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;background:grey;
    min-height:400px;
}
.menu {
    background:blue; width:100%; text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: "I wish to put a navigation menu below this div, but i can't nest it with the other div." Why do you have to nest it? A div is a block element, so when you put a div after a div, it appears below it.

Comment: Does `.content` is constant height?

Comment: Content isn't a constant height. That makes it difficult

Comment: @desbest not when one of the fivs is absolutely positioned

Answer (score 3):

We know the 'position' of the bottom of the content block so we can use `calc`

```
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top:calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: grey;
  min-height: 50vh;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Hello world</div>
<div class="menu">home | info | about us | contact</div>
```

That said, bbsolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. See [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: I know absolute positioning isn't the way to go, but this isn't for a website but for a slideshow app. it uses a specific framework so i can't/don't want to change to much of the existing html/css

Comment: Thanks. The menu should stick to the content div. i changed the min-height to 400px. When the viewport is smaller then 400px the menu should stay below the content div

Answer (score 2):

As requested, here is a `position:absolute` way. With this one I used another solution than calc(), as calc() sometimes can have unexpected results.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.menu,
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-width: 400px;
}
.menu {
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    top: auto;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Hello world</div>
<div class="menu">home | info | about us | contact</div>
```

A version using `display: table`, works with IE8, and for newer browsers we also have flex as an option (not showed here).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.page-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.page-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 0;
}
.page-cell-expanded {
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: #999;
}
.menu {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;  
  background-color: #99f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="page-row">
    <div class="content page-cell page-cell-expanded">
        Hello world
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="page-row">
    <div class="menu page-cell">
        home | info | about us | contact
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I know absolute positioning isn't the way to go, but this isn't for a website but for a slideshow app. it uses a specific framework so i can't/don't want to change to much of the existing html/css

Comment: @RemcovandenBerg Updated my answer and added a "position:absolute" way

Comment: My example wasn't correct. I've updated my code example to have a min width in 400px. the menu div should still stick to the bottom of the content div, even when the screen is smaller then 400px.

Comment: @RemcovandenBerg Updated both samples again according to your new request.

Comment: @RemcovandenBerg Should the content div at all times cover the browser viewport (minus the margins set) ? .. If so, what do you want the `min-height: 50vh;` to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can help you.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/9p4a1567/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Hello world</div>
    <div class="menu">home | info | about us | contact</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    position:relative;
}
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
.content {
    background:grey;
    min-height:50vh;
}
.menu {
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```